# Use Dash-core-components.Upload to upload a csv file and save it in the project directory for use by other scripts

Tags: python, plotly-dash

After using the example from the docs, for dcc.Upload, I am able to save the csv file in my project directory by using `to_csv(location2)`, location2 is a file string to my project directory ('E:/dash_app/components/new.csv')

it important to note that the goal is to have a multipage project where I can toggle the displayed screen from a dropdown in a navbar. so the project should run correctly until the csv file is uploaded and there after it will display all the graphs and charts and information that is returned from the csv.file .

My project structure looks as follows:

```
Dash_app 
  __pycache__ 
  .vscode 
  Components 
       Import_csv.py 
       csv_clean.py 
  app.py 
  Index.py 
  requirements
```

Under components directory there are many more components that get imported into index.py.

I `import import_csv` into index.py, the `dcc.Upload` component is in csv_upload.py, therefore by running index.py it runs import_csv.py where the csv file can be uploaded into my directory.

The problem is that I use functions from csv_clean.py to take the uploaded csv file as an input in order to return values so that I can use those values in other scrips in the 'components' directory (for graph and card modules).

The input to all the functions in csv_clean.py will be location2.

I receive the error:  `in " csv_clean.py data = pd.read(location)" no such file or directory exist : location2`

The csv_clean.py script looks like as follows:

```
`` Import pandas as pd from components.import_csv import import location2

 def daily_roi_income(file):
      csv_df = pd.read_csv(file)
      roi = csv_df.loc[csv_df.Remark=='Roi Income', ['Date', 'Credit']] 

      return roi


 Roi = daily_roi_income(location2) 

``
```

So this function cannot work unless the csv file exists. And I cannot run Index.py to upload the csv unless this works.

What is an approach to take if code is dependent on other code to run first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your problem is that you are running your code on a remote machine, and you don't know how to get the data file that it reads onto the remote machine?

Comment: maybe for reference i should add the github rep. https://github.com/Choli4king/Dash_app.git     .  for test purposes I am running the script on my local server. In my opinion it would not matter if it were a remote server. I feel it is a matter of the timing of the script execution. I cannot try read a csv file in a piece of code if the file does not exist yet. the project needs to run once in order to download the file first.